# A Bridge Scorecard I can reuse, that can be discussed to the right

Tags: tables, layout

I am interested in duplicating the standard bridge scorecard for inclusion in a book, the discussion will refer to the scorecard (possibly with highlighting parts of it). I expect the scorecard to be perhaps half the width of the page perhaps?

```
\usepackage[]{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l c c c}
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\colorbox{black}{\color{white}Scoring for Bridge}} \\
  VALUE PER TRICK &  Not doubled & Doubled & Redoubled \\
  \midrule
  IF TRUMP IS:& & & \\
  Clubs or Diamonds (\clubs, \diamonds) & 20 & 40 & 80 \\
  Hearts or Spades (\hearts, \spades) & 30 & 60 & 120\\
  NO TRUMP CONTRACT:& & & \\
  1st trick over 6 & 40 & 80 & 160 \\
  Each additional trick over 6 & 30 & 60 & 120 \\
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Game is 100 Points} \\
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{First side to win 100 points below line, in one or more hands, wins a game}} \\
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{When a side wins two games, a rubber is concluded.}} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{PREMIUM SCORE}} \\
  \midrule
\end{tabularx} \\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l r r r r r r}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{NOT VULNERABLE} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{VULNERABLE}\\
  & Not Dbld. & Dbld. & Redbld. & Not Dbld. & Dbld. & Redbld. \\
  \midrule
  Each overtrick & Trick Value & 100 & 200 & Trick Value & 200 & 400 \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textit{(Tricks made in excess of contract)}} \\
  \midrule
  Small Slam (12 tricks) & 500 & 500 & 500 & 750 & 750 & 750\\
  Grand Slam (13 tricks) & 1000 & 1000 & 1000 & 1500 & 1500 & 1500\\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Two-Game Rubber\dotfill 700} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Three-Game Rubber\dotfill 500} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Unfinished Rubber, One Game\dotfill 300} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Unfinished Game, Part Score\dotfill 100} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Bonus for fufilling any doubled contract\dotfill 50} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Bonus for fulfilling any redoubled contract\dotfill 100} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Honours (Scored above the line by either side)} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Four of the five trump Honours (A, K, Q, J, 10) in one hand\dotfill 100} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{All five trump Honours (A, K, Q, J, 10) in one hand\dotfill 150} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{All four Aces in one hand at notrump contract\dotfill 150} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{UNDERTRICK PENALTIES}} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{NOT VULNERABLE}} & Not Doubled & Doubled & Redoubled \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{One\dotfill 50} & 100 & 200\\
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{Two\dotfill 100} & 300 & 600\\
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{Three\dotfill 150} & 500 & 1000\\
  \multicolumn{4}{l}{For each additional undertrick} & Add 50 &  Add 300 & Add 600\\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{VULNERABLE}} \\
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{One\dotfill 100} & 200 & 400\\
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{Two\dotfill 200} & 500 & 1000\\
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{Three\dotfill 300} & 800 & 1600\\
  \multicolumn{4}{l}{For each additional undertrick} & Add 100 &  Add 300 & Add 600\\
  \midrule
\end{tabularx}\\
\textit{Doubling and/or redoubling do not affect honour, slam or rubber points.}\\
\textit{Vulnerability does not affect honour points or bonus points.}\\
\textit{The side making the most points at the conclusion of the rubber (regardless of games) is the actual winner of the rubber.}
```

which yields the following results with my other preamble.

[image: my scorecard]

My target is this

[image: target]

This is closeish - I would like to be able control its size a bit better? Perhaps putting it in  minipage?

My LaTeX is not very strong so I am looking for strategies that would help? Are tables the right way to go? I would like the whole thing to be shrunk to about half the size and hopefully draw boxes or callouts to be able to refer to parts it.

Are nested tables a good idea?

Also I am not sure why the two tables are not aligned.

I hope I have provided enough detail and am asking the right questions here?

Comment: Reduse the width of the `tabularx` to, say, `0.5\textwidth` and/or reduce the font size.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding teh documentclass you use as well as the relevant packages. Could you please also explicitly point out what exactly you would like to change about your table? Is it just the width/height and font size or something else?

Comment: Regarding the alignment issue: Place a `\noindent` right before the first `tabularx`. Apart from that,  a `tabularx` only really makes sense when used in combination with its `X` type column. Since you don't seem to need a column that allows its contents to occupy multiple lines while being of a flexible width, a simple `tabular*` would already be sufficient.